# Unexpected response code 500 when performing request on Android 6.0.1

Tags: android, web-services, android-volley

I am facing the problem with Android Volley when running this code, I tested this on Android version 5.0.1 is work fine, but on Android version 6.0.1 it exists

> error: E/Volley(22302): [15348] BasicNetwork.performRequest:
>       Unexpected response code 500 for https://site/OutletService.asmx/update_outlet

Do you have any idea about this? your help is highly appreciate.

```
    Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
    map.put(Constant.User.AccessKey, accessKey);

    JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray();
    jsonArray.put(toJSONObject());
    map.put("Content-Type", "text/html; charset=utf-8");
    //map.put(Constant.ListOutlet, String.valueOf(toJSONObject()));
    map.put(Constant.ListOutlet, jsonArray.toString());

    Log.i("SubmitData", map.toString());
    ServerStringPostRequest submitRequest = new ServerStringPostRequest(map, ip + Constant.prefixtServerUpdateOutlet, new Listener<String>() {

        @Override
        public void onResponse(String responses) {
            Log.i("Update", responses);
            try {
                JSONObject response = new JSONObject(responses);
                String code = response.getString(Constant.code);
                if (code.equals("1")) {
                    uploadImageForOutlet(context, ip, accessKey, callBack);
                    // callBack.onSuccess(OutLet.this);
                } else if (code.equals("0")) {
                    callBack.onFail(OutLet.this);
                }

            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
```

Answer (score -1):

If U r facing problem only in Android 6 . then it seems the problem about run time permission in your app. So add all manifest permission at run time in your java code(Activity) like as :

```
This is only for sample

// Here, thisActivity is the current activity
if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(thisActivity,
                Manifest.permission.INTERNET)
        != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

    // Should we show an explanation?
    if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(thisActivity,
            Manifest.permission.INTERNET)) {

        // Show an explanation to the user *asynchronously* -- don't block
        // this thread waiting for the user's response! After the user
        // sees the explanation, try again to request the permission.

    } else {

        // No explanation needed, we can request the permission.

        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(thisActivity,
                new String[]{Manifest.permission.INTERNET},
                MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_INTERNET);

        // MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_READ_CONTACTS is an
        // app-defined int constant. The callback method gets the
        // result of the request.
    }
}
```

For complete ref. see these links

[link 1](https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html)

[link2](http://www.androidhive.info/2016/11/android-working-marshmallow-m-runtime-permissions/)

Comment: The same problem still exists. what to do then?

Comment: I already added <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.PERMISSION_GRANTED" /> and <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" /> in AndroidManifest.xml file but the same error exist.

03-30 15:58:06.524: E/Volley(22302): [15348] BasicNetwork.performRequest: Unexpected response code 500 for https://site/OutletService.asmx/update_outlet

Comment: I already told you for establish run time permission. here your manifest permission not works

Comment: ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, permission);

the checkSelfPermission is undefined in ContextCompat class, because I am using android 4.4.2 SDK (API 19). any idea about that?

Comment: it meant this package is not available in API level 19.

Comment: if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.ICE_CREAM_SANDWICH) {

}

Comment: now using this U can run more than one type of code in same app.

Comment: error still exists,checkSelfPermission not definded in android.support.v4.content.ContextCompat;

Comment: Can you tell me what type of permission is that since all data is text. it is not about access camera etc...

Comment: I already added permission, but still the same. What is your suggestion?